# Stuck on a lift on Noveria!

Tags: mass-effect

I appear to be stuck on a lift.

After re-establishing landline communications, I got back into the lift to return back inside the facility, and after the lift came to a stop and the doors open I found myself unable to move. The game is still responding because I'm still getting Mira's voice overs telling me the power is down but the game is otherwise not accepting any movement. I am also still able to look around.

[image]

It is not possible to save the game (the save option is greyed out), which would have presumably allow me to reload the game again and resolve the problem. My last auto-save is a couple of missions back (about an hour ago) so I'd rather avoid loading that back up if I can avoid it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The reason you can't save isn't (directly) related to the bug you're experiencing: you simply can't save on elevators in this game.

Comment: yeah, I ended up loading and making sure I created a save before dealing with the lifts again!

Comment: http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2007/11/16

Comment: That's odd, it should have saved just after you re-established the communications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another way that I just found but requires the console to be activated.

> First, enable the console by going to Documents>BioWare>Mass
>   Effect>Config on your computer. Then open BIOInput in Notepad. Find
>   the line [Engine.Console] and under it add the line ConsoleKey=Tilde.
>   Then when playing in game simply press the tilde key (above tab) to
>   open the console, then type in the desired cheat.

Then if the glitch happens just open the console and type in **walk** and then try again!

Comment: Been a while since I replayed the trilogy, just started Mass Effect 1 again the other day and strangely this same bug occurred so I got a chance to confirm that this works

Answer (score 3):

After some experimentation and research I am concluding that this is a bug and that there is no way out of it. While the game is still fully responsive, you can't move.

Some articles I found as a result of my googling suggested that potentially using cheats might allow me to get passed this issue, however I tried both the `fly` and the `ghost` cheat at the console and neither of these allowed me to start moving again.

The only option was to simply reload my last save and catch back up to where I was at in the story.